# Python 2 binary search

Tags: python, performance, binary-search

I wanted to take a stab at implementing a binary search, and here's what I came up with. Is there anything I could have done better, from  a code clarity perspective, or code optimization perspective? Any and all criticism would be appreciated:

```
import random
# implement a binary search

def binary_search(alist, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1
    found = False
    midpoint = None
    while True:
        midpoint = first + ((last-first) // 2)
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            return midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] < item:
            first = midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] > item:
            last = midpoint

def _create_search_criteria(cap=10000):
    # choose a target to search for
    choice = random.randrange(0, cap/2)
    # create some data full of random numbers
    data = [random.randrange(0, cap/2) for i in xrange(cap)]
    # ensure the choice is nowhere in the data
    data = [d for d in data if d != choice]
    # put a single of instance of choice back into the data
    data[random.randrange(0, cap)] = choice
    # sort the data
    data = sorted(data)
    return data, choice

def test_binary_search():
    data, choice = _create_search_criteria()
    print 'Searching for: ' + str(choice)
    index =  binary_search(data, choice)
    print 'Found it at index: ' + str(index)
    assert data[index] == choice

for x in xrange(1000):
    test_binary_search()
```

Comment: You declare `found` in `binary_search` and then never use it. The last term could also be else, because if it's not greater than or equal, it has to be less than.

Comment: Thanks! I was using found before, but forgot to remove it when I took a different approach.  I'll make sure to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the source of Python's `bisect` module in the standard library to see the accepted implementations used for binary searches and binary insertions used in the language:

```
"""Bisection algorithms."""

def insort_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Insert item x in list a, and keep it sorted assuming a is sorted.

    If x is already in a, insert it to the right of the rightmost x.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    a.insert(lo, x)

insort = insort_right   # backward compatibility

def bisect_right(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e <= x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e > x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just after the rightmost x already there.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if x < a[mid]: hi = mid
        else: lo = mid+1
    return lo

bisect = bisect_right   # backward compatibility

def insort_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Insert item x in list a, and keep it sorted assuming a is sorted.

    If x is already in a, insert it to the left of the leftmost x.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if a[mid] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    a.insert(lo, x)


def bisect_left(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):
    """Return the index where to insert item x in list a, assuming a is sorted.

    The return value i is such that all e in a[:i] have e < x, and all e in
    a[i:] have e >= x.  So if x already appears in the list, a.insert(x) will
    insert just before the leftmost x already there.

    Optional args lo (default 0) and hi (default len(a)) bound the
    slice of a to be searched.
    """

    if lo < 0:
        raise ValueError('lo must be non-negative')
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)
    while lo < hi:
        mid = (lo+hi)//2
        if a[mid] < x: lo = mid+1
        else: hi = mid
    return lo

# Overwrite above definitions with a fast C implementation
try:
    from _bisect import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Regarding your code, let us see what improvements can be made:

```
def binary_search(alist, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1
    found = False
    midpoint = None
    while True:
        midpoint = first + ((last-first) // 2)
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            return midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] < item:
            first = midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] > item:
            last = midpoint
```

The initial values of `found` and `midpoint` are never used and so can be removed:

```
def binary_search(alist, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1
    while True:
        midpoint = first + ((last-first) // 2)
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            return midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] < item:
            first = midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] > item:
            last = midpoint
```

My tests are being performed in Python 3.5, so the code may looks slightly strange. What happens when searching for something that does not exist?

```
def binary_search(alist, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1
    while True:
        midpoint = first + ((last-first) // 2)
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            return midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] < item:
            first = midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] > item:
            last = midpoint

alist = list(range(10, 20))
item = 9
print(binary_search(alist, item))
```

The function enters an infinite loop if the value is too small. What about when the value is too large?

```
def binary_search(alist, item):
    first = 0
    last = len(alist)-1
    while True:
        midpoint = first + ((last-first) // 2)
        if alist[midpoint] == item:
            return midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] < item:
            first = midpoint
        elif alist[midpoint] > item:
            last = midpoint

alist = list(range(10, 20))
item = 10
print(binary_search(alist, item))
```

The program prints out zero. This is not correct either. Here is a rewrite of your code in hopes to correct the problem:

```
import random


def main():
    for _ in range(1000):
        array = sorted(random.sample(range(10000), 9000))
        value = random.randrange(10000)
        index = binary_search(array, value)
        if index is None:
            assert value not in array
        else:
            assert array[index] == value


def binary_search(array, value):
    start, stop = 0, len(array)
    while start < stop:
        offset = start + stop >> 1
        sample = array[offset]
        if sample < value:
            start = offset + 1
        elif sample > value:
            stop = offset
        else:
            return offset

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. Definitely helpful to see the de facto standard implementation of what I am doing, but was hoping to have my code scrutinized rather than just see what someone else did.

Comment: Thanks for the update! That's exactly what I was hoping for. And also to know if there are any blatant performance issues. Much appreciated!!